# Generate new worksheet based on column data for LARGE spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with 800k rows and 150 columns. I'm attempting to create new worksheets based on the contents of a column. So, for example if column Y has many elements ("alpha", "beta", "gamma", etc.) then I'd like to create new worksheets named "alpha", "beta", "gamma" which contain only the rows from the original that have those respective letters. I've found two scripts that work for smaller spreadsheets, but due to the size of this particular spreadsheet, they **don't work**.

Here are the two scripts that I have tried:

```
Sub parse_data()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = 1       
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")       
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1:C1"           
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
    ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
    Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
End Sub
```

this returns "overflow"

the other code that I have tried:

```
Sub columntosheets()

Const sname As String = "VOTERFILE_WITHABSENTEEINFORMATI" 'change to whatever starting sheet
Const s As String = "O" 'change to whatever criterion column
Dim d As Object, a, cc&
Dim p&, i&, rws&, cls&
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With Sheets(sname)
    rws = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    cls = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    cc = .Columns(s).Column
End With
For Each sh In Worksheets
    d(sh.Name) = 1
Next sh

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(sname))
    Sheets(sname).Cells(1).Resize(rws, cls).Copy .Cells(1)
    .Cells(1).Resize(rws, cls).Sort .Cells(cc), 2, Header:=xlYes
    a = .Cells(cc).Resize(rws + 1, 1)
    p = 2
    For i = 2 To rws + 1
        If a(i, 1) <> a(p, 1) Then
            If d(a(p, 1)) <> 1 Then
                Sheets.Add.Name = a(p, 1)
                .Cells(1).Resize(, cls).Copy Cells(1)
                .Cells(p, 1).Resize(i - p, cls).Copy Cells(2, 1)
            End If
            p = i
        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Sheets(sname).Activate

End Sub
```

Returns error with "excel does not have enough resources".

Is it possible to do what I want on my hardware?

Comment: Change your `Integer` variables to `Single` and the top code should work, albeit slowly. I'd convert that to using arrays. Or better yet, why are you using Excel for 800K+ rows? Seems like a database might be more appropriate.

Comment: SQL Server Express is a free download and handles millions of rows like a charm. The error you're getting is Excel crying *dude, I'm not a database, leave me alone*. Excel is a formidable hammer. Too bad not every data-driven problem is a nail.

Comment: "why don't you use a database?" is an obvious question to posters who are using Excel for huge amounts of data, but i think we're often too quick to forget what it was like when we were just starting out with coding - I know i had *absolutely no idea* what a "real" database was, let alone any idea of how to go about setting up and using one. Sometimes the hammer is the only thing accessible to you.

Comment: This is not data that I am creating. It's .txt file I downloaded from a website. This is probably an extremely newbie question, but how big is the learning curve for SQL server express? I just need to compute a couple of stats.

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess that was more of a suggestion in the form of a question :). It's a valid point. I just wish I would have learned about/how to use databases earlier.

Comment: @faeophyta, I'm a relative SQL newbie, and I would say the learning curve (for basic functionality) is not too steep. You can pretty easily load a `.txt` file to SQL and then query from that.

Comment: @Kyle, any pointers of what to do? I'm on the import export wizard with no idea what to export to. Is there a tutorial I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the modified subroutine in another article '[Macro for copying and pasting data to another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332285/macro-for-copying-and-pasting-data-to-another-worksheet/40155560#40155560)'.

```
Sub CopySheet()

Dim wsAll As Worksheet
Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowCrit As Long
Dim I As Long

Set wsAll = Worksheets("All") ' change All to the name of the worksheet the existing data is on

LastRow = wsAll.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

' column G has the criteria eg project ref
wsAll.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

LastRowCrit = wsCrit.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 2 To LastRowCrit

     wsAll.Copy Before:=Sheets("All")
     ActiveSheet.Name = wsCrit.Range("A2")
     Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
     Unique:=False
     wsCrit.Rows(2).Delete

Next I

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsCrit.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```