# Macro for copying and pasting data to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I found the below code to copy and paste data from one worksheet to another based on a unique identifier. It also renames the worksheet as the unique identifier :)

It works really well apart from that formulas now appear as numbers.

Please does anyone know how to amend the code so that the actual formulas are kept :-

```
Dim wsAll As Worksheet
Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowCrit As Long
Dim I As Long

Set wsAll = Worksheets("All") ' change All to the name of the worksheet the existing data is on

LastRow = wsAll.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

' column G has the criteria eg project ref
wsAll.Range("D1:D" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

LastRowCrit = wsCrit.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 2 To LastRowCrit

    Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add
    wsNew.Name = wsCrit.Range("A2")
    wsAll.Rows("1:" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
     CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A1"), Unique:=False
    wsCrit.Rows(2).Delete

Next I

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsCrit.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: you'll need to filter normally and pastespecial I believe

Comment: Thanks. I had tried amending it but I couldn't get it to work. It is only 1 line that needs changing :-  wsAll.Rows("1:" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
     CopyToRange:=wsNew.Range("A1"), Unique:=False

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to use 'AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy' as it will convert the formula to value.  Instead, use 'AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace' which will retain the formula.  I have modified the code to reflect this.

```
Sub CopySheet()

Dim wsAll As Worksheet
Dim wsCrit As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowCrit As Long
Dim I As Long

Set wsAll = Worksheets("All") ' change All to the name of the worksheet the existing data is on

LastRow = wsAll.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsCrit = Worksheets.Add

' column G has the criteria eg project ref
wsAll.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

LastRowCrit = wsCrit.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For I = 2 To LastRowCrit

     wsAll.Copy Before:=Sheets("All")
     ActiveSheet.Name = wsCrit.Range("A2")
     Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=wsCrit.Range("A1:A2"), _
     Unique:=False
     wsCrit.Rows(2).Delete

Next I

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wsCrit.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```